# get the list of arguments sent to a shell script

Tags: shell, parsing, arguments

I am sending arguments to my shell script from Java program, I know the code accesses the shell script and sends the arguments, but I can not see those arguments. 
How can I get a list of them?

Comment: You mean in the shell script ? If so have you tried `$@` ?

Comment: I have tried it,strangely it didn't work before, but now it's working. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the list of args passed to shell script using :

```
echo $@
```

If you want to individually traverse the args use `echo $N`, however if the argument is not passed at Nth position `echo $N` will not throw any error instead it'll not show nothing.

You can use `echo $#` to find out the no. of arguments passed.

Comment: echo $@ does show a list of arguments, but echo $N outputs 0.Does it mean the arguments are not passed at Nth position? Can I put them into the right position iterating through them?

Comment: That means argument is there at `nth` position and its value is 0. You can check the no. of arguments passed by using `echo $#`, however I don't think you can change the position of the actual arguments passed. Although you can copy them into another array and manipulate that.